# Dynamic Component render along side Angular Universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I am trying to load dynamic components in my view and i did achieve the same using [Angular Docs Site Source Code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/aio/src/app/layout/doc-viewer/doc-viewer.component.ts) as reference. But the entire piece has been written using document and various selectors, which is only available on the browser. However I want to render the content from server side using angular universal to make my site SEO friendly. Can somebody help me on how it can be achieved.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I made a small demo to show how that code can be implemented in your own application https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-content-viewer?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: _this.hostElement.querySelectorAll is not a function, this is the error I am getting when universal tries to render the page.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved in @angular version 5-beta-6 with platform-server moving from parse5 (DOMAdapter) to domino (actual DOM implementation).